# find lines that don't end with 'rpms' with sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I would like to find lines that do not end with 'rpms' with sed in Linux.

I have tried below:

```
sed -ne '/?!(rpms$)/p'
```

But unfortunately, it is not correct.

Comment: What do you want to do? To just get lines that *don't* end in `rpms` you should use `grep(1)`, e.g. `grep -v 'rpms$' file`

Comment: If the existing answers solved your problem, please consider accepting it with the checkmark; thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it in sed is to:

- not print lines by default (`-n`)
- search for the given pattern (`/rpms$/`)
- and print only if the pattern is *not* matched (`!`)

putting it all together:

```
sed -n '/rpms$/ !p'
```

For more reading, here's one [sed tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-32), linked to the pertinent section on reversing the pattern matching.

Alternatively in sed, you could

- print lines by default
- but delete matching lines (`d`)

Putting that together yields:

```
sed '/rpms$/ d'
```